# How to add RegExp to an angular 8 directive to support negative decimal number?

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, angular-directive

I have the following directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[signedNumeric]'
})

export class SignedNumericDirective {
   
    private regex = {               
        decimal: new RegExp(/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/g)
    };                          
    private specialKeys = {       
        decimal: [ 'Backspace', 'Delete', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight' ]
    };

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', [ '$event' ])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {

        if (this.specialKeys['decimal'].indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        // Do not use event.keycode this is deprecated.
        // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode
        let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex['decimal'])) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how how use the directive in the template:

```
<input type="text" name="sample" id="sample" autocomplete="off"
                                  [(ngModel)]="decinmalVal" maxlength="6" signedNumeric>
```

This worked for positive decimal such as 34.45 0.7 1200.6 BUT it's not allow negative.
I've try to update the RegExp to:

```
decimal: new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/g)
```

with no success. The reg exp was tested online but it doesn't work in the directive. I don't know what wrong.

Comment: Well you updated regex should be working.  How is it not working?

Comment: I have no idea why I can't use the "-" key I'll add the input tag to the q

Comment: I guess I need a new regular expression that works

Comment: [It works, check the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbDfDK/1).

Comment: Can you share the regular exp you come with ?

Comment: Ahh sorry It's a link, checkiong now

Comment: The regular expression work in the link but in my code it doesn't work, so there is another problem with the directive

Comment: Try `/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/` - no `g`. Then, try `/^-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?$/` if you need a live input validation.

Comment: wow thank you @WiktorStribiżew I;ve tried the second option and it's just works! And you are right it is live input, I have an array of elements on the screen and each elem use the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex for live input validation

```js
/^-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?$/
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `(?:\.\d*)?` - an optional sequence of a dot and then zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string.